# javascript use return in forEach

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if the question title is proper, but I just ran into the problem when I tried to use this function.

In the first one all the output is `NaN`, but in the second one the code works. I don't understand why the first one cannot work, what causes this different result.

Hope you could help me out.

Thanks a lot!

```
//1

function sum(...rest) {
   var sum=0;
   sum+=rest.forEach(function (value){
      return value;
   });
   return sum;
}

sum();
sum(1);
sum(2,3);


//2

function sum(...rest) {
   var sum=0;
   rest.forEach(function (value){
      sum+=value;
   });
   return sum;
}

sum();

sum(1);
sum(2,3);
```

Comment: Read the docs of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: i deleted it like 10 seconds after i posted it because i read over it.

Comment: @user2415266, thank you. I should've done that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return a value [by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Better to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you want this behaviour:

```
function sum(...rest) {
   return rest.reduce(function(prev, next) { return prev + next; });
};
```

Comment: Your code have an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: Thanks @YosvelQuintero fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Davin, It is my fault that I did not research forEach() to know that its return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use `forEach` in the way you did in the first example.

What you need is `Array.prototype.reduce`.

That can accumulate the values from iterations, like this:

```
function sum(...rest) {
  return rest.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return result += item;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map()` function for get sum of each element. get dynamic arguments by `arguments` variable

```js
function sum() {
  var sum=0;
  var args=[];
  for(i in arguments) args.push(arguments[i]);
  if(args.length>0){
    sum = args.reduce(function(total, value) {
        return total + value;
    });
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Why you don't use "Rest parameters"?

Comment: @Arnial, according to example OP wants sum of all arguments which is passed in function.. but he has misunderstanding how to use dynamic parameters

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a function which only returns 1 `undefined` no matter how many times the function inside the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) runs. So you're essentially appending 1 `undefined` to the sum.

You can use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function which is somewhat similar to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) except it returns a result after iterating over all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of `sum()` function with the use of [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and adding an initial value equal to zero:

```js
let sum = (...rest) => rest.reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0);

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
console.log(sum(-3, -5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an arrow function and a start value.

```js
var sum = (...rest) => rest.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum(2, 3));
```